# JQuery delegate not firing in IE8 and lower

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code below where I setup global variables, set elements to these variables and then assign a delegate change event on a dropdown.

The change event fires in all browsers except IE8 and lower. Not too bothered about IE7 and lower.

Any help appreciated?

```
$(function () {
    initialisePage();
});

function initialisePage() {
    window.portfolioGroupFilters = $("#portfolioGroupFilters");
    window.portfolioGroupsList = $("#portfolioGroupsList");
    window.portfolioGroupAccounts = $("#portfolioGroupAccounts");
    window.coverSheetsList = $("#coverSheetsList");
    window.coverSheetsPanel = $("#coverSheetsPanel");
    window.reportGroupsList = $("#reportGroupsList");
    window.reportGroupPanel = $("#reportGroupsPanel");
    window.searchResults = $("#searchResults");
    setportfolioGroupFiltersdelegates();
}

function setportfolioGroupFiltersdelegates() {
    portfolioGroupFilters.delegate(".availableFilters", "change", function () {});
}
```

Comment: What version of Jquery are you using?

Comment: If you're using a newer version of jQuery (greater than 1.7) - switch to on()

Comment: try live() instead of delegate or .on()

Comment: Using version 1.4.2. Tried on() and live() but neither work.

Comment: strongly suggest using a more up-to-date version; 1.4 is quite old now.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using jQuery 1.7 or greater, the best solution is to use `on()` instead of `delegate()`.

Your code using `on()` will be:

```
portfolioGroupFilters.on("change", ".availableFilters", function () {});
```

Also, it's good to know that `live()` is deprecated: http://api.jquery.com/live/

> As of jQuery 1.7, the `.live()` method is deprecated. Use `.on()` to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use `.delegate()` in preference to `.live()`.

Comment: Can't upgrade JQuery at the moment.

Comment: @user2385566 - you may want to consider using [Google's library option](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide)